# Models of Comprehension Schema

Tags: set-theory, problem-solving

> Let $M_\alpha$ for $\alpha\in ON$ be transitive sets and let $M=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON}M_\alpha$. Suppose that (i) for every $\alpha<\beta$, we have $M_\alpha\in M_\beta$ and (ii) for every limit $\lambda$, $M_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} M_\alpha$. Prove that if for arbitrarily large $\alpha\in ON$, $M_\alpha$ satisfies the comprehension schema, then $M$ satisfies the Comprehension schema.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think I actually managed to figure it out (just uses a relatively strong reflection result I had forgotten about). For any instance of the comprehension schema $\psi$, you can find a club of ordinals $C$ such that $\psi$ is absolute for $M_\alpha$ and $M$, $\alpha\in C$. So since you can find a $\beta\in C$ with $M_\beta$ a model of $\psi$, and thus so is $M$

Comment: I don't follow the last sentence of your argument - how do you get such a $\beta\in C$? (Keep in mind that the complement of a club may also be unbounded!)

Comment: I guess I was just taking "arbitrarily large $\alpha\in ON$" to be synonymous with "each $\alpha\in ON$'". Is that not the same?

Comment: No, it's not - it means that the class of $\alpha$ such that $M_\alpha$ satisfies comprehension is unbounded in $ON$. (Although you're right, that's pretty unclear.)

Comment: I see. Well, I guess I'm back to square one. Though I suspect that some reflection principle is still involved. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you have to combine two observations, but actually
get away with weaker assumptions:

Proposition. Let $(M_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in \operatorname{On})$ be a
sequence such that $M_{\alpha}$ is transitive,
$M_{\alpha} \in M_{\beta}$ for all
$\alpha < \beta \in \operatorname{On}$,
$M_{\lambda} = \bigcup \{ M_{\alpha} \mid \alpha < \lambda \}$ for
limit ordinals $\lambda$ and such that the set of $\alpha$'s such that
$M_{\alpha}$ satisfies comprehension for $\Sigma_{1}$ formulas is
unbounded. (We can get away with comprehension for $\Sigma_{0}$
formulas, if we know that our $M_{\alpha}$'s are closed under
pairing.) Then
$M := \bigcup \{ M_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in \operatorname{On} \}$
satisfies full comprehension.

Proof. Let $\phi(v_{0}, \ldots, v_{n-1})$ be a formula in the language
of set theory with exactly $v_{0}, \ldots, v_{n-1}$ as free variables
and let $p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n-1} \in M$. We want to see that

$$\{x \in p_{1} \mid M \models \phi(x,p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n-1} \} \in M.$$

Fix $\alpha < \operatorname{On}$ such that
$\{p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n-1} \} \subseteq M_{\alpha}$ and such that
$\phi(v_{0}, p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n-1})$ is absolute between $M_{\alpha}$ and
$M$. (Such an $\alpha$ exists by the Reflection Principle, because
$(M_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in \operatorname{On})$ is a strictly
increasing and continuous sequence of transitive sets.) Let
$\alpha < \beta \in \operatorname{On}$ be such that $M_{\beta}$
satisfies comprehension for $\Sigma_{0}$ formulas. Now, in
$M_{\beta}$, the statement
$$x \in p_{1} \wedge M_{\alpha} \models \phi(x,p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n})$$
can be expressed as a $\Sigma_{1}$ formula in paramaters
$p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n}, M_{\alpha}$. (Again, we actually can do a
little better. This formula can be set up in a way that it actually
does not depend on the formula $\phi$ itself, but only on its rank in
the Levy hierarchy.) Since it may also be expressed in a $\Pi_{1}$
way, we get (by the absoluteness of $\Delta_{1}$ formulas between
transitive structures, that
$$\{x \in p_{1} \mid M_{\alpha} \models \phi(x,p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n-1})
\} = \{x \in M_{\beta} \mid M_{\beta} \models \left( x \in p_{1}
  \wedge M_{\alpha} \models \phi(x, p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n-1}) \right)\}
\in M_{\beta} \subseteq M.$$ qed

Comment: I didn't provide all the details (e.g. I didn't justify how the modeling relation can be expressed in a $\Delta_{1}$ fashion, provided the models has the structure in question as a member). So, if anything is unclear, please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Everything is crystal clear except the part that the modeling relation can be expressed as $\Sigma_1$

Comment: @R.Thomas Since you are assuming full comprehension anyways, you may safely ignore this technical detail. Writing down why this is true, is quite tedious. I could send you my handwritten notes in which I spelled out all the details, beginning by construction a Goedel numbering and ending in the aforementioned result.